# How to stop a swing timer without terminating?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm using a swing timer to get the x-position of a moving object every second for 10 seconds and save it in an array. Right now, the only way I can stop the repeat of the timer is using System.exit(0);. How do I stop the timer and continue executing the rest of the code?

```
int k=0;
{
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {

            obj1pos[k]=x;
            System.out.println(obj1pos[k]);
            k+=1;
        }
        if (k>=10){
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                System.out.print(obj1pos[i]+", ");}
            System.exit(0);}


     }
};

new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionEvent` will pass you the `source` that generated the event, which, in this case, is the instance of the `Timer`

So you can just cast the `ActionEvent#getSource` to a `Timer` and call `stop` on it when you need to...

```
if (k>=10){
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.print(obj1pos[i]+", ");
    }
    System.exit(0);
    ((Timer)(evt.getSource())).stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the timer accessible throughout the class by defining a private Timer at the top of your class;

```
private Timer timer;
```

Then define the timer as you do before by stating:

```
timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

And then in your if just call:

```
timer.stop();
```